# How can we sort list of objects by attribute value of each object?

Tags: python, pulp

I have a list object which looks in the debuggers as follows:

[image]

As you can see, the elements of list are ordered alphabetically. That is at index `02`, it has element `10`, instead of `2`. Also note that each element is actually an object of type `pulp.pulp.LpVariable` and the number we see in list are actually value of each object's `name` property (as can be seen on the last list of image). Pulp seem to alphabetically sort its variables.

I want this list numerically sorted by name of each object. That is I want `2` at index `2`, `3` at index `3` and so on.

I tried below:

```
>>> from pulp import *
>>> prob = LpProblem("lp", LpMinimize)
>>> dvs = {}
>>> for i in range(20):
...     dvs[i]=LpVariable(str(i))
... 
>>> prob += lpSum(dvs.values())
>>> prob.variables()
[0, 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> prob.variables().sort(key=lambda x:int(x.name))
>>> prob.variables()
[0, 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

As you can see, sorting is simply not happening. I expected output on the last line to be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `prob.variables()` does but the fact that is is a callable makes me strongly suspect that you are not referring to the same list when you sort it and when you print it, but getting a new list each time you call `prob.variables()`

Please try the following:

```
result = sorted(prob.variables(), key=lambda x:int(x.name))
print(result)
```